# Targeting the last list item

Tags: css, styles, substring, listitem, css-selectors

```
<ul id="nav-items" class="links">
                            <li><a href="http://www.thevoiceofjeremydonahue.com/about">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.thevoiceofjeremydonahue.com/projects">Projects</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.thevoiceofjeremydonahue.com/contact">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
```

I am working with this unordered list that you see above.  Ultimately I'm trying to target the last list item "Contact" in order to style it slightly different than the rest.  Now to be very specific this is how my css looks so far for this particular list:

```
#nav-items {
    border: 2px solid white;
    background: rgb(255, 75, 0);
    border-radius: 10% 10% 80% 80%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    margin-right: 1px;
    font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif;
    font-size: 40px;
}


#nav-items > li {
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    margin-right: 58px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    background: black;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 2px solid white;
}

#nav-items > li a:hover {
    color: white;
    border-radius: 50%; /*This one (border-radius) isn't working either*/
}
```

Now, in order to target the last one my first choice was to go for

```
a[href$="contact"] {
     property: "value";
}
```

but that didn't work...so I tried

```
#nav-items:last-child {
     property: "value";
}
```

I've even tried

```
ul li a {property: "value"}
```

that didn't work, and on top of that I wouldn't have wanted to do it that way anyway because I have other anchors inside of list items elsewhere on the page that I don't want affected

I've also tried all of the other substring matching attribute selectors ~, ^, *...and none of those worked either...

I've tried

```
#nav-items > li a {property: "value"}
```

nothing...

there's probably a couple things that I've tried that I can't remember...

essentially I'm trying to affect the border-radius of the very last list item

I've even validated both my HTML and CSS just to be sure

I've got nothing...you?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were pretty close..

You have to actually tell it to choose the last `li`, rather than the last `#nav-item` - there's only one.

```
#nav-items li:last-child {
     property: "value";
}
```

[**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/y498h/) - it works..

Additionally, you don't want `#nav-items li a:last-child {}` - note the `a`.. as that will choose the last `a` - not the last `li`. In context there are no `a` elements beside each other anyways.

Comment: Ha!  I swore I tried that...but considering I hadn't gotten it to work yet, I'm going to go with I must not have.  Hooray to you my friend!  You have defeated the beast, and I thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
#nav-items li a:last-child {
    property: "value";
}
```

The CSS *last-child* selector check if the element which it is applied on is the last child of its parent. This is why your previous code didn't work as expected :

```
#nav-items:last-child {
    property: "value";
}
```